# Why does pdflatex/dinbrief produce a US letter page for this input?

Tags: paper-size, letters

I want to write a simple letter using the dinbrief class but cannot get it to produce a DIN A4 page. The minimal example is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\subject{Some subject}
\backaddress{Me, some address}
\signature{Me again}
\Datum{Someplace}
\address{my name\\someplace\\some city}
\begin{letter}
{Other guy\\
his city}
\opening{Dear pdfLaTeX,}

why don't you produce the proper page size?

\closing{Kind regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This produces a US letter sized document when I run `pdflatex document` from the terminal. I run ubuntu 12.04 with texlive-full packages installed and updated.
I would assume the a4paper option in the header is pretty unambiguous...

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Note that `texlive-full` is outdated (TeXLive 2009). There is no current version of TL for Ubuntu/Debian at the moment. It is recommended to install TL 2011/12 over its own installer.

Comment: I know this can happen during dvi2ps conversion, but if you run pdflatex directly that should not happen.

Comment: @MartinScharrer are there any alternatives to TL that are packaged under Ubuntu? I somewhat dislike the idea of installing a huge set of packages without proper package management.

Comment: @black_puppydog: TL comes with its own proper package management (`tlmgr`) and will be installed in a single directory (`/usr/local/texlive` usually). There are no binary dependencies between TL and other tools, like editors, so there is no issue here.

Comment: @black_puppydog try the TL installer provided by TL http://tug.org/texlive/ never ever use the ubuntu repos. For package management within TL, TL delivers the so call `tlmgr` utility.

Comment: Probably your TeX Live is set up with US Letter paper as default for `pdflatex`. I don't know how to set it to A4 on Debian, but a workaround is to say `\usepackage[a4paper,pass]{geometry}` in the document preamble.

Comment: @MartinScharrer it was the packages. I installed texlive from their site and now it just works. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14):

Quite a lot of old classes (e.g. `article` or your `dinbrief`) don't set the pdf sizes. An option like `a4paper` sets only things like the TeX `\paperwidth`, the linewidth and similar lengths.

You will have to insert the necessary command yourself. For pdflatex this is

```
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
```

For latex/dvips you need a `\special{...}`.

You can also load one of the packages `graphicx`, or `hyperref`, or `geometry` which will set the pdf lengths for you.

Btw: The people who can't reproduce your problem probably have a4paper as default. In this case they would see your problem if they used e.g. the option `letterpaper`.

Answer (score 4):

With Ubuntu 12.10 the default paper size of `pdflatex` can be changed by running

```
sudo paperconfig -p a4
```

This changes some configurations including `/etc/papersize`, which was set to `letter`. Beware that there is also a command named `paperconf`, which does not change anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).