# g-brief produces letter format PDF instead of A4 depending on system settings

Tags: pdf, paper-size, letters

I'm using `g-brief` to produce a letter. However, on my computer, the resulting PDF has the letter format, whereas I need A4. I figured `g-brief` only produces A4 PDF files, so I'm surprised. When I compile the exact same tex file on a different computer, the correct PDF in A4 format is produced. It appears that g-brief uses some sort of system setting to determine the format. I changed the content of `/etc/papersize` to `a4`, but the problem persists. Both computers run Debian (but different versions: Jessie and Wheezy).

I can force the output to A4 by using the `geometry` package, but then the footer disappears. How do I get LaTeX to produce the correct format?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{g-brief} \begin{document} x \end{document}
```

This produces a PDF file in the letter format on my computer, and in the A4 format on the other computer I was talking about.

Edit: I can't answer anymore because this question has been linked to another question, which has an answer that doesn't solve my problem. However, I found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61930/why-does-pdflatex-dinbrief-produce-a-us-letter-page-for-this-input): run `sudo paperconfig -p a4`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. (g-brief ist etwas veraltet ;-))

Comment: I edited my question. I doubt it's a problem of g-brief's age, but for what it's worth, the problem also happens with g-brief2.

Comment: Where is `g-brief2` available?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is included in TeX Live.

Comment: I guess you installed your TeX distribution with the general advice to produce letter format (Question while installation).  If that is so you have to force LaTeX to produce DIN A4.  As far as I remember that could be option `pagesize` or simular.  Please search this side, there is an answer for this. Sorry I do not remember ...  Please add a compilable minimal working example to play with ...

Comment: @Volker: I'll try later on, but now I have to teach students...

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been linked to the other, similar question. There, the suggested solution is to use the `geometry` package. First, this doesn't explain the different behavior on different machines, and second, I already mentioned that I tried doing so and it removes the footer, so it's not a solution.

Comment: @Volker --- the answer to the linked question *does* explain how you can get different behaviour on different machines.

Comment: @IanThompson No, using `geometry` does not solve this particular problem with `g-brief2`. I'm having the exact same problem as the OP. This question should not be closed.

Comment: @MichaelGoerz --- I didn't close it, but I can see why others did. The issue with different behaviours on different machines is explained in the linked answer. The disappearing footer problem is not reproduced by the example code (at least not on my machine). If you have run into the latter problem, it might be easier to ask a new question than to try resurrecting this one.